# Create new object in component out of variables in the same component Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

I want to use my variables, which values can be changed in html through [(ngModel)], for creating a new object newUser of type Testuser.

In the html there are input fields for firstName, lastName and so on which I want to send to a database with a click on a button.

There is a second row of fields with firstName, lastName and so on.
If I click on another button I want to show values of a database in those seperate fields.

component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {TEST_USER_EMPTY, TestUser} from './testUser';
import {TestService} from './test.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  id = 0;
  lastName = '';
  firstName = '';
  isActive = true;

  // user with empty content
  user: TestUser = TEST_USER_EMPTY;

  // todo create new user with ngModel values for add user
  newUser: TestUser;


  constructor(private testService: TestService) {
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchUserFromServiceId();
  }

  changeStatus(): void {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }

//this function works

  fetchUserFromServiceId(): void {
    console.log('%cWerte:', 'color: orange;', this.id, this.isActive, this.lastName, this.firstName);
    this.testService.getUserById(this.id).subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
      } else {
        alert('no user found');
      }
    });
  }



  // this function needs the variables from above, but doesn't accept it

  addUserFromService(): void {
    this.testService.addUser(this.newUser).subscribe(() => alert('Post done'));
  }



  showCurrentUser(): void {
    console.log('ID:' + this.id + ' Last Name: ' + this.lastName + ' First Name: ' + this.firstName);
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
addUser(newUser: TestUser): Observable<TestUser> {
    return this.http.post<TestUser>(this.testUrl, newUser);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending newUser in addUser function of testService. So you must declare newUser with empty values like you did with user variable. And you must bind newUser in html also.